# LayoutView that shows any number of views

Tags: marionette

If I have a LayoutView which has two regions defined,
`myLayout.getRegion('regionA').show(myView1)`
`myLayout.getRegion('regionB').show(myView2)`
This is fine.

myView3 cannot be appended because myLayout does not have a third region, and the template has no more placeholder either.

If I want to have a LayoutView (or whatever container) which accepts an array/ordered collection of **any number of views** and show them simply as one  after another, what should I do?

(I think the answer is not CollectionView as it expects one childView and a Collection of Models.)

Comment: [Discussion of the same topic](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/1691)

Answer (score 1):

If you have models attached to the views, the answer is CollectionView, it has a nice getChildView method that is used to find proper view class based on the properties of the item model, see [CollectionView docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-getchildview)

If you don't care about the models then idea of [MultiRegion](https://github.com/joezimjs/MultiRegion) class will work for you — it allows multiple views to be attached to single Region. It is quite outdated now though, feel free to send a pull request if you will update it to latest Marionette version

Comment: If I don't need to care about models.  Whatever views are given, I just show them.  Is CollectionView still the answer?  @AlexPonomarev

Comment: No, CollectionView will not work in this case, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation:
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layoutview.md

1. Marionette region, can be a defined as a function

> Regions can be specified on a LayoutView using a function that returns
>   an object with the region definitions. The returned object follow the
>   same rules for defining a region, as outlined above.

```
 Marionette.LayoutView.extend({   // ...

   regions: function(options){
     return {
       fooRegion: "#foo-element"
     };   },

   // ... });
```

2. You can addRegion to the LayoutView

> Regions can be added and removed as needed, in a LayoutView instance.
>   Use the following methods:
>
> ```
> addRegion
> addRegions
> removeRegion
> ```

So you can just addRegion to Layout, before showing new element

Try this:

```
            layout.addRegion("region1", "#region1");
            layout.$el.append("<div id='region1'/>");
            layout.region1.show(panelView);
```

It worked for me

Comment: You can addRegion to the LayoutView, but the new region needs a selector (#foo-element), which the template does not have?

Comment: So append it to your HTML, using jquery layoutView.$el

Comment: `$('body').append(myLayout.$el);`   I see the wrapping element (tagName), which is empty, in DOM.  `myLayout.render();`  and I see myLayout's template in DOM.  Views are made to show in `myLayout.onBeforeShow = ... region1.show(myView1);`     , and views are not shown.  I see only myLayout's template in DOM.   How to make myLayout show?

Answer (score 0):

After spending days trying to write a LayoutView that accepts an arbitrary number of views,  I have made it, but then found [Backbone Babysitter](http://jsfiddle.net/rayweb_on/fxzAs/) which is tidy.

```
new Backbone.ChildViewContainer();
```